# How to validate 00-00-00-0000 format on text oninput() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

The code work properly here .. but according to problem its not work properly actually I want to validate the 00-00-00-0000 format a text in digit/alpha .. but this code work only first time fill the value then its work correct but after the clear text the fill the value validation work not properly.

```js
var v = "0";
var v1 = "0";
var v2 = "0";

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("vname");
  x.value = x.value.toUpperCase();
  var add = "-";
  var string = x.value;
  var str = "";
  var len = string.length;
  if (len > 13) {
    x.value = string.substring(0, 13);
  }
  if (len > 2 && v == "0") {
    var str = x.value;
    x.value = setCharAt(str, 2, '-');
    v = "1";
  }
  if (len > 5 && v1 == "0") {
    var str = x.value;
    x.value = setCharAt(str, 5, '-');
    v1 = "1";
  }
  if (len > 8 && v2 == "0") {
    var str = x.value;
    x.value = setCharAt(str, 8, '-');
    v2 = "1";
  }
}

function setCharAt(str, index, chr) {
  if (index > str.length - 1) return str;
  return str.substr(0, index) + chr + str.substr(index + 1);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" oninput="myFunction()" id="vname" />
```

Comment: Try work with regex like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50890663/html-form-validation-with-regex-in-javascript-using-getelementbyid

Comment: You should use the validation API instead.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation

Comment: thank u so much for reply .. actually i  want validation put hand to hand if (-) not enter at particular position then autoamtically - add  in string

Comment: Would [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55010378/5459839) be useful?

Answer (score 2):

The issue you're currently facing is due to the fact that you set some state by changing the `v`, `v1` and `v2` variables. Your formatter should be stateless so it returns the same result every time you call it with the same input.

You could use a templating string. Then loop through the input value index, for each index check in the templating string what is allowed.

```js
function myFunction(input) {
  const format = "xx-xx-xx-xxxx";

  var value = ""; // new value
  for (let i = 0; i < input.value.length; ++i) {
    switch (format[i]) {
      case "-":
        value += "-";
        break;
      case "x":
        value += input.value[i];
        break;
    }
  }
  
  input.value = value.toUpperCase();
}

document
  .getElementById("vname")
  .addEventListener("input", event => myFunction(event.target));
```

```html
<input type="text" id="vname" />
```

Comment: Things go wrong when you put the cursor in the middle of the already present characters and start typing/deleting there.

Comment: @trincot true, but the intent of this answer is to keep the behaviour close to the question. Only providing what's actually asked.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex, hope it will help you:

```
 ^([0-9]|[a-z])|([0-9]|[a-z])(\-)([0-9]|[a-z])|([0-9]|[a-z])(\-)([0-9]|[a-z])|([0-9]|[a-z])(\-)([0-9]|[a-z])|([0-9]|[a-z])([0-9]|[a-z])|([0-9]|[a-z])$
```

Comment: thanku so much for reply  .. i want to perform oninput() hand to hand validate the text

Comment: you can try the below code:

`function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("vname");
    x.value = x.value.toUpperCase();
    var add = "-";
    var string = x.value;
    var len = string.length;
    var validationString = string.charAt(len-1);
    var re = new RegExp("^([a-z]|[0-9])$");
    if(len == 3 || len == 6 || len == 9) {
    if(validationString != '-')
 return false; 
    }else {
  return (re.test(validationString));
    }
}`

Comment: The `|` characters between two `([0-9]|[a-z])` groups shouldn't be there. It's hard to easily explain since it seems you're new to regex. Have a [look](https://regexper.com/#%5E%28%5B0-9%5D%7C%5Ba-z%5D%29%7C%28%5B0-9%5D%7C%5Ba-z%5D%29%28%5C-%29%28%5B0-9%5D%7C%5Ba-z%5D%29%7C%28%5B0-9%5D%7C%5Ba-z%5D%29%28%5C-%29%28%5B0-9%5D%7C%5Ba-z%5D%29%7C%28%5B0-9%5D%7C%5Ba-z%5D%29%28%5C-%29%28%5B0-9%5D%7C%5Ba-z%5D%29%7C%28%5B0-9%5D%7C%5Ba-z%5D%29%28%5B0-9%5D%7C%5Ba-z%5D%29%7C%28%5B0-9%5D%7C%5Ba-z%5D%29%24) for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a more generic answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55010378/5459839) on using a visible mask for a fixed-size formatted input. That should work for you, if you accept that the input mask is always visible. For it to work add the following attributes to your `input`:

```
<input placeholder="__-__-__-____" data-slots="_" data-accept="\w" size="13">
```

Note that it does not turn lower case into upper case (something I would advise against: you don't want people to think their CAPS-lock key is malfunctioning).
If that is not how you want it to work (with the mask or with the lack of upper-casing), here is that code adapted to your requirements specifically:

```js
const el = document.getElementById("vname"),
    pattern = "__-__-__-____",
    prev = [1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 7, 8, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13],
    accept = /\w/g,
    clean = input => {
        input = input.match(accept) || [];
        return Array.from(pattern, c =>
            input[0] === c || c == "_" ? input.shift() || c : c
        );
    },
    format = () => {
        const [i, j] = [el.selectionStart, el.selectionEnd].map(i => {
            i = clean(el.value.slice(0, i)).indexOf("_");
            return i<0? prev[prev.length-1]: back? prev[i-1] || 0: i;
        });
        let s = clean(el.value).join``.toUpperCase();
        el.value = s.slice(0, (s+"_").indexOf("_"));
        el.setSelectionRange(i, j);
        back = false;
    };
    
let back = false;
el.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => back = e.key === "Backspace");
el.addEventListener("input", format);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="vname" />
```

Like in the answer I referred to, this also deals with copy/paste (even if copied values do not have the hyphens), with selections, putting the cursor halfway, deleting characters there, ...etc.

Comment: Which part of your code do you need to keep? I am suggesting to replace it all as does not work well.

Comment: actually its i putting the js code in script tag nd html code putting the html tag but vaalidation is not working here

Comment: Then you do something wrong. Check the snippet in my answer

Comment: If you need help then post a fiddle that demonstrates how it does not work for you

Comment: See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xk45hj3L/1/). It works. Just do *exactly* the same.

Comment: thank u so much ... its work correctly ..according to my need